# Combining multiple CSS elements

Tags: css

What would be the best way to combine these CSS elements?

As my web page grows I'm quite concerned about maintenance. There is not much difference between the below, apart from the bg image used, so I was wondering if there could be a way to make the code more maintainable.

```
#section3 {
    background: url(../img/img2.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    #section3 {
        height: 30em; 
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    #section3 {
        height: 50em;
    }
}

#section5 {
    background: url(../img/img3.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    #section5 {
        height: 30em; 
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    #section5 {
        height: 50em;
    }
}

#section7 {
    background: url(../img/img4.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    #section7 {
        height: 30em; 
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    #section7 {
        height: 50em;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using SASS/SCSS, which allows CSS nesting and repeatable functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest something like this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c7t8qkmk/).

```
#section3 {
    background: url(../img/img2.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}

#section5 {
    background: url(../img/img3.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}

#section7 {
    background: url(../img/img4.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}

#section7, #section5, #section3 {
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    #section7, #section5, #section3 {
        height: 30em; 
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    #section7, #section5, #section3 {
        height: 50em;
    }
}
```

Perhaps you have also a look at **LESS** or **SASS**.